# Retrieve data from two tables in PHP Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I want to retrive count of datas from one table and some datas from another table , also i want to know how to display these in a single foreach loop.

> Model

```
public function counter(){
    $this->db->where('package_id', $id);
    $this->db->from('gt_package');
    $cnt = $this->db->count_all_results();
}
```

> Controller

```
public function package_category_listing()
{
    $data['records'] = $this->gt_package_model->counter();
    $query = $this->db->get("gt_package_category");
    $data['records'] = $query->result();
    $this->load->view('admin/package/package_category_listing',$data );
}
```

> View part :

```
<?php foreach ($records as $r) { ?>    
        <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-3 col-xs-12">
            <div class="bg-purple">
                <h4 class="text-white">
                    <?php echo $r->category_name; ?>
                </h4>
                <span>200</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;Packages
                <br>
                <a style="margin-top: 10px;" href="<?php echo site_url() . "/gt_package/listing/" . $r->category_id ?>" class="btn btn-default">View Packages</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    <?php } ?>
```

Comment: change the code `$cnt = $this->db->count_all_results();` to `$query = $this->db->get('gt_package'); $cnt = $query->num_rows();`

Comment: how can i call this in view

Comment: Any foreign keys connecting table `gt_package` and table `gt_package_category`. if so join these two tables

Answer (score 0):

As per your question to pass the data model to controller code bellow

Model:

```
 public function counter()
{
        $this->db->where('package_id', $id);
        $this->db->from('gt_package');
        $query = $this->db->get('gt_package');
        $cnt = $query->num_rows();
        return $cnt; 
}
```

Controller:

```
public function package_category_listing()
{
    $data['records'] = $this->gt_package_model->counter();
    $query = $this->db->get("gt_package_category");
    $data['records'] = $query->result();
    $this->load->view('admin/package/package_category_listing',$data );
    if($res){
        $data['result'] = $res;
        $this->load->view('manage_accounts_view', $data);

    } else {

        echo "Fail";

    }
    print_r($data['result']);
}
```